# Error showing - "Blink deferred a task in order to make scrolling smoother"

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to build ionic(1) app using angular. 
I do not understand why am i getting this warning

"Blink deferred a task in order to make scrolling smoother. Your timer and network tasks should take less than 50ms to run to avoid this. Please see https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/evaluate-performance/rail and https://crbug.com/574343#c40 for more information."

And additional warnings when i am using page sliders is

"Ignored attempt to cancel a touchmove event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted."

"Handling of 'touchstart' input event was delayed for 835 ms due to main thread being busy. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive"

Comment: I saw this too once today on Honor 7 Lite - it was as if the button that triggered the transition was inactive - but I realized that I could touch-scroll horizontally to the next screen. The transition didn't work until the whole app had been restarted.

Comment: This is the kind of question that is unlikely to get much attention, even with a bounty, because it doesn't include any specifics that might help troubleshoot the problem beyond making an attempt to re-explain the error documentation.  If you *truly* are interested in assistance, then some indication of what it is you are actually trying to do, for example which ionic modules you are calling and in what order, would help.

Answer (score 4):

This warnings are "normals". The webview is basically telling you that some events are bound to the scroll event or even the touch event and that might slow down the app. The google docs recommend for instance to use intervals instead of running calculations or functions directly on the touchmove/drag events, which is not always possible with a mobile app with webview depending on what you are trying to accomplish UX wise.

Moreover, if you do use a setInterval, you will have to use crazy aggressive timings like 10ms and your scroll/drag will look really bad.
Just forget these warnings, they are very generic and most likely guidelines but most of the time can't be avoided.

If you still want to avoid the warning, here is a jQuery example. The idea is to catch whatever values from the event and then run calculations on a separate thread.

```
 var int, x, y;

 $('#mydiv').on('touchstart', function(event){
      int = setInterval(work, 20);
 });

 $('#mydiv').on('touchend', function(event){
      clearInterval(int);
 });

 $('#mydiv').on('touchmove', function(event){
      x = event.touches[0].pageX;
      y = event.touches[0].pageY;
 });  

 function work(){
      //how you can do whatever with x y without getting a warning 
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be unrelated, but from my experience, basically you're getting this because your angular/page is still intensively processing. I used to get this warnings if I tried to scroll too quickly after navigating to a new state -- if I waited a sec it would be ok. My solution was to disable the js scroll to release more power to where it was more relevant. Check `scrolling.jsScrolling(value)` on http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/provider/$ionicConfigProvider/

Answer (score 0):

These are actually serious warnings. I have spent way too long time on this warning. If there is long running javascript task like timer or network task then it will be stopped until you are scrolling.then when scrolling is done these tasks are resumed.So took special care while implementing these heavy processing tasks.